# How to count students and classes of every teacher in SQL Server?

Tags: sql

Assume 3 tables like this:

**Teacher:**

```
teacher_id, name, ...
```

**Student:**

```
student_id, teacher_id, ...
```

**Class:**

```
class_id, teacher_id, ...
```

Is there a SQL query to get how many students and classes are assigned to every teacher?

Result should be something like this:

```
teacher_id  name    students    classes 
t_001       AAA        3           2 
t_002       BBB        1           2 
...
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! Then you don't need any of those messy `&nbsp;` and `<br/>` tags, either!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    t.teacher_id, t.name,
    Classes = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Class c WHERE c.teacher_id = t.teacher_id),
    Students = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Student s WHERE s.teacher_id = t.teacher_id)
FROM teacher t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with teacher_students as (
  select t.teacher_id,
         t.name,
         count(s.student_id) as students
    from Teacher t
    left outer join Student s
      on t.teacher_id = s.teacher_id
   group by t.teacher_id, t.name
),
teacher_classes as (
  select t.teacher_id,
         count(c.class_id) as classes
    from Teacher t
    left outer join Class c
      on t.teacher_id = c.teacher_id
   group by t.teacher_id
)
select ts.teacher_id,
       ts.name,
       ts.students,
       tc.classes
  from teacher_students ts
  join teacher_classes tc
    on ts.teacher_id = tc.teacher_id
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
SELECT       T.TEACHER_ID
           , T.NAME,
           , COUNT(C.TEACHER_ID ) AS   CLASSES
           , COUNT(S.TEACHER_ID ) AS   STUDENTS
FROM TEACHER T 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CLASS C
ON  T.TEACHER_ID = C.TEACHER_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN STUDENT S 
ON T.TEACHER_ID = S.TEACHER_ID
GROUP BY T.TEACHER_ID, T.NAME
```

Comment: This will give the wrong counts. It permutes all the Teacher-Student rows with all the Teacher-Class rows. A teacher with 3 students and 2 classes will be listed as having 6 students and 6 classes.