# How to count the number of students taught by each teacher?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database that has the following tables

```
Courses: CourseID*, CourseName, TeacherID
Teachers: TeacherID*, TeacherName
Students: StudentID*, StudentName
StudentCourses: CourseID*, StudentID*
```

*Legend:* * is the primary key.

How can I write to query that produces produces the number of students taught by each teacher?

For example

```
TeacherName, Count
Bob 15
Sarah 5
Zubair 1
```

Edit

```
select "TeacherName", count(*)
from courses inner join teachers on courses."TeacherID" = teachers."TeacherI"
join sutdentcourses on sutdentcourses."CourseID" = courses."CourseID"
group by "TeacherName"
order by "TeacherName";
```

Comment: This is a very basic aggregation query with a `join`.  You should at least try.

Comment: @idclark you need teachers and students. The only thing that relates them is courses. So you will need to join that data. Now, you need count of students per teacher so you are looking at aggregate functions. With this knowledge come up with a SQL and then we can guide you further if you still don't get it right. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/ and take a look at JOIN and GROUP BY.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  is there a more efficient way than my solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count students and classes of every teacher in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914305/how-to-count-students-and-classes-of-every-teacher-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

You need make JOIN between the tables Teachers, Courses and StudentCourses, Group your records by TeacherName and Count the StudentID.

```
SELECT TeacherName, COUNT(StudentID)
FROM Teachers JOIN Courses USING(TeacherID)
JOIN StudentCourses USING(CourseID)
GROUP BY TeacherName
```